# How to return an animation to it's original state if the button is clicked again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Now it may be a little bit of a dumb question (probably is), but i just can't wrap my head around it. So i have a navigation bar that is horizontally and vertically centered with a button inside of it. If you click the button the nav bar animates to the top of the page with a little bit of margin left. What i'm trying to achieve is when the button is clicked again the nav bar would animate back to it's original position. I've tried many lines of code and i still can't get it right (shouldn't even be that hard). Any help is appreciated.

JavaScript:

```
$("#btn").click( function(event){
    $("#wrapper").animate({
        'top': 100
    }, 400) 
});
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}

#nav {
    margin:20px auto;
    height:200px;
    width:900px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#bca;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/birdhouse/LUM8k/4/)

Comment: save the state before you the original action, another click revert the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like that:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUM8k/5/)

```
$("#btn").click( function(event){
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    $("#wrapper").stop().animate({
        'top': this.toggle?100:"50%"
    }, 400)
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Works perfectly, as does the one posted by adeneo, however this at least to me looks way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a `clicked` variable which can tell you if it has been clicked or not (or similar) then on 1st click, move up, on second click, move down and so on.

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/LUM8k/8/)

```
var clicked = false;
$("#btn").click( function(event){
    clicked = !clicked;
    if(clicked)
    {
        $("#wrapper").animate({
            'top': '-=100'
        }, 400)
    }
    else
    {
        $("#wrapper").animate({
            'top': '+=100'
        }, 400)
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't really seem to work all that well. The nav bar doesn't move to the top of the page. Thanks for explaining how it works thought. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jquery UI [switchClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/) plugin. or in a ugly way by updating your code like:

```
$("#btn").click( function(event) {
    var top = $("#wrapper").css('top') == '100px' ? '50%' : 100;
     $("#wrapper").animate({
        'top': top
      }, 400)
});
```